# как проверить, что кнопка была нажата

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Не могу понять, почему функция on_button_click() не работает от слова "совсем"

```
import discord

from discord.commands import Option
from discord import guild
from discord.ext import commands

# Intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    print("работает ивент")
    if interaction.custom_id == "button_verif":
        await interaction.response.send_message("Вы нажали кнопку!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.dnd)
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")

@bot.command(name = "verif")
async def verification(ctx):
    view = discord.ui.View()
    button_verif = discord.ui.Button(label = "Верификация", custom_id = "button_verif", style = discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    view.add_item(button_verif)

    if ctx.author.id == 111111:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Верификация",
            description = "Чтобы получить роль <@&1107286502825795624> нужно нажать кнопку «Верификация» под этим сообщением. После нажатия вы отправите запрос, который будет рассмотрен и после подтверждения вам выдадут роль.",
            color = discord.Color(0xFFFFFF)
        )
        
        await ctx.send(embed = embed, view = view)

bot.run(Token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class MyView111(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Верификация", , custom_id = "button_verif", style = discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        print("работает ивент")
        if interaction.custom_id == "button_verif":
            await interaction.response.send_message("Вы нажали кнопку!")
@bot.command(name = "verif")
async def verification(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == 111111:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Верификация",
            description = "Чтобы получить роль <@&1107286502825795624> нужно нажать кнопку «Верификация» под этим сообщением. После нажатия вы отправите запрос, который будет рассмотрен и после подтверждения вам выдадут роль.",
            color = discord.Color(0xFFFFFF)
        )
    await ctx.send(embed = embed, view = MyView111())
```

Comment: Это работает, но после перезапуска бота это перестаёт работать. В случае, если я отправлю сообщение и буду с ним взаимодействовать - всё ок. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А после перезапуска бота не может работать. Это возможно только в случае, когда бот будет каждые несколько минут редактировать сообщение с кнопкой, т.к. Дискорд выключает кнопку через несколько минут. Если помог, поставьте галочку и проголосуйте:)

Comment: Но вот например с модулем Disnake такого нет. Там можно сделать постоянный обработчик одной кнопки.